# Have PAE still got 4GB

Tags: debian, kernel, pae

Trying to get more than 4GB RAM on 32 bit CPUs with PAE, but can't.

```
~# grep -o pae /proc/cpuinfo 
pae
pae
pae
pae
~# uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-6-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) i686 GNU/Linux
~# grep HIGHMEM /boot/config-4.9.0-6-686-pae 
# CONFIG_NOHIGHMEM is not set
# CONFIG_HIGHMEM4G is not set
CONFIG_HIGHMEM64G=y
CONFIG_HIGHMEM=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_HIGHMEM is not set
~# dmidecode -t memory | grep Enabled
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Single-bank Connection)
```

Still got

```
~# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G         29M        3.6G         10M        244M        3.5G
Swap:            9G          0B          9G
```

Maybe someone can help, where do I look?

Comment: What motherboard do you have?  Some motherboards are limited to 4GB.  See `Hardware support` on [this Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)

Comment: Does the BIOS show more than 4GiB? Are there related options in the BIOS setup ("remapping")?

Comment: @TimothyMartin Motherboard is 8IPXDREL-GG, specs say up to 12GB

Comment: @HaukeLaging BIOS shows (and checks at POST) 6GB. I could not find any related options in BIOS.

Comment: What does `dmidecode -t memory | grep -i "size\|maximum"` report?

Comment: @TimothyMartin `~# dmidecode -t memory | grep -i maximum
     
 Maximum Memory Module Size: 4096 MB
     Maximum Total Memory Size: 24576 MB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To diagnose memory problems, the best place to start is the kernel boot messages; the kernel prints out everything it finds concerning the system’s memory. Start with the output of `dmesg`, looking for “memory”.

As you discovered, in your case this shows

```
[ 0.000000] WARNING: BIOS bug: CPU MTRRs don't cover all of memory, losing 2176MB of RAM.
[ 0.000000] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-rtbsTs/linux-4.9.82/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mtrr/cleanup.c:978 mtrr_trim_uncached_memory+0x2f5/0x326
```

which suggests that the BIOS isn’t setting things up properly for a 6GiB system.